# Use iPod Touch 5th or 4th generation for development?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ipod-touch

I am developing an iOS application for a school project.

My application requires some functions :

- JSON data exchange
- Photo upload

In my point of view, either iOS5 or iOS6 will suit my requirements.

**My Questions are :**

1. Concerning the development in the future,  is it better to buy an iPod Touch 5th generation instead of 4th?
2. If I develop for an iPod Touch 5th gen.will my app be backward compatible with the previous iOS if its screen is taller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the iPod Touch 4 and 5 will serve you well for development.

If the iPod Touch 4 has still iOS 5 installed, then you can test iOS 5 on the phone and iOS 6 in the simulator. But even if your device has iOS 6 installed, you can still develop for iOS 5. With the simulator, you can test other iOS version.

It's similar for the screen size. You can write apps that are compatible with both screen sizes and you can test them both with the simulator.

Of course, you cannot test telephony functions on an iPod. But this doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Comment: Um .. with Xcode 4.5 simulator can run iOS 4, 5 and 6, for standard iPhone, 3.5 inch retina and 4 inch retina screen devices.  You just need to install the earlier simulators from the XCode Preferences.  However having a real device is still necessary for final testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
So I should create different xib files/storyboards for different screen sizes :)?

Comment: No, you can configure a XIB file to automatically adapt to the screen size. Just search on SO. There are many questions and answers about this topic.